# water running but wont run hot through the kitchen only

Tags: hot-water

we have hot water in all other parts of the house, but not in the kitchen? the water will come through cold and not become hot.  If we turn the laundry hot water on, it will turn the kitchen hot water on, but the pressure is at half strength.

Comment: Has it always been this way, or is this new? If new, what changed recently (outside temperature, perhaps)? Is the plumbing visible from the basement or anywhere else? Is there a chance the plumbing lines to the kitchen sink are not insulated or directly exposed to outside (freezing) temperatures?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the cartridge inside of the sink faucet has failed. Some cartridges have a special mixing valve that reacts to changes in pressure to prevent large temperature swings when, for example, a toilet is flushed. If this is the case, you'd have a single handle faucet, and if you disconnected the hot water from the shutoff under the sink, you should have full water pressure when you open that shutoff valve (into a large bucket). To fix it, get a replacement that specific to your faucet and follow the instructions that comes with the replacement. When disassembling a faucet, it's a good idea to place something (usually a towel) in the drain to prevent any lost parts.